# How to query jsonb?

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

I am storing settings into a config field as:

```
  schema "teams" do
    field :owner_id, :integer
    field :is_base_team, :boolean
    field :config, :map
    has_many :team_users, {"team_user", App.TeamUser}
  end
```

So, I need to build query that reads parameter `see_owner` within `config` as:

```
teams_users =
    from(t in Team, where: t.owner_id == ^user_id and fragment("?->>'see_owner' == ?", t.config, true))
    |> Repo.all()
    |> Repo.preload(:team_users)
```

However, I got error:

```
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR (undefined_function): operator does not exist: text == boolean
        (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:395: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.execute_and_cache/7
        (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:127: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.execute/5
        (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:40: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.all/4
        (app) web/channels/user_socket.ex:67: App.UserSocket.get_team_users_ids/1
        (app) web/channels/user_socket.ex:40: App.UserSocket.connect/2
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/socket/transport.ex:167: Phoenix.Socket.Transport.connect_vsn/6
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/transports/websocket.ex:73: Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket.init/2
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/cowboy_websocket.ex:12: Phoenix.Endpoint.CowboyWebSocket.init/3
        (cowboy) src/cowboy_handler.erl:64: :cowboy_handler.handler_init/4
        (cowboy) src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

So, how would I add to my query a checking of `config.see_owner` where `config` is a `jsonb` where `see_owner` is a `boolean` property ?

I am using `ecto 2.0.0-rc.5`

**EDIT**

I have fixed the postgres query as:

```
from(t in Team, where: t.owner_id == ^user_id and fragment("?->> 'see_owner' = '?'", t.config, true))
```

in the log I, it was translated as:

```
SELECT t0."id", t0."owner_id", t0."is_base_team", t0."config" FROM "teams" AS t0 WHERE ((t0."owner_id" = $1) AND t0."config"->> 'see_owner' = 'TRUE') [3]
```

but the result is empty, however, there *are* teams with config equals to {"see_owner": true}

**EDIT2**

Checking with owner_id, I got error:

```
sql> SELECT t0."id", t0."owner_id", t0."is_base_team", t0."config" FROM "teams" AS t0 WHERE ((t0."owner_id" = $1) AND t0."config"->> 'see_owner' = 'TRUE') [3]
[2016-06-01 17:43:33] [42804] ERROR: cannot subscript type boolean because it is not an array
```

I removed the owner_id check, but I got empty result:

```
SELECT t0."id", t0."owner_id", t0."is_base_team", t0."config" FROM "teams" AS t0 WHERE (t0."config"->> 'see_owner' = 'TRUE')
[2016-06-01 17:44:09] 0 rows retrieved in 9ms (execution: 4ms, fetching: 5ms)
```

I removed the owner_id check, and I used small letters for `'see_owner' = 'TRUE'` as `'see_owner' = 'true'`, I got the results without errors:

```
sql> SELECT t0."id", t0."owner_id", t0."is_base_team", t0."config" FROM "teams" AS t0 WHERE (t0."config"->> 'see_owner' = 'true')
[2016-06-01 17:46:40] 16 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 7ms (execution: 3ms, fetching: 4ms)
```

so, I think that Ecto needs to translate boolean type to postrgres native query without converting it to capital letters like `TRUE` or `FALSE` as it currently does.

also, I don't know why native query with owner_id got error, as I copied the resulted native query from logs, and it should be working correctly..

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your conditional, `==` is not valid in PostgreSQL.

Try this:

```
from(t in Team, where: t.owner_id == ^user_id and fragment("?->>'see_owner' = ?", t.config, true))
```

Comment: kindly see EDIT above

Comment: Do you definitely have that value set for that particular owner_id? Try removing the `t.owner_id == ^user_id and` from your query.

Comment: I already tried to remove `t.owner_id == ^user_id and` but I still got empty value, I tried to run the query outside phoenix, kindly see *edit2* above

Comment: Could you please provide an example user row or struct with the value set to true?

Comment: I can confirm that using boolean in Ecto's fragment would convert it to uppercase in the native postgres query, which results in error, as it should be small letter like(true, false) but currently its exported at (TRUE, FALSE)